# This simple MySQL join will not work for me

Tags: mysql, variables, join, self-join

Each individual query (t1 and t2) works fine by itself, however a simple join is seemingly not allowed.

I recreated the code using tables x1 and x2 and it was fine, however copy pasting t1 and t2 over the top gets me an error again.

It must be something to do with the variables?

**problematic attempt**:

```
select *
from
( 
set @rownumber1 = 0;
select  (@rownumber1:= @rownumber1 + 1) as num,
    id,
    updated_at as date,
    risk_factor
from (select * from user.users_audit order by id) orig
order by id 
) t1

left join
(
set @rownumber2 = 0;
select  (@rownumber2:= @rownumber2 + 1) as num,
    id,
    updated_at as date,
    risk_factor
from (select * from user.users_audit order by id) orig
order by id 
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

**working attempt - but with tables I dont care about**:

```
select *
from
(
select *
from sport_type_sources
) x1

inner join
(
select *
from sport_type_sources
) x2 on x1.id = x2.id
```

I would simply like to join the two tables.

Comment: If you state that it "gets me an error again", you should also add that error to your question

Comment: I needed to declare the variables before the initial select statement...

Comment: Before digging more on what may not even be applicable.  Can you edit your question and please restate what you are trying to do in simple statements, not SQL (but leave the SQL)...  Ex:  I want to compare blahA and blahB for purpose of ...  What is your whole purpose of the @variable values if you already have the ID.  Is there some other table with an ID?  Can you show some SAMPLE data and what you expect.